# Every almost $r$-regular graph has a spanning almost $(r-1)$-regular subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

**Definition.** A Graph is *almost $r$-regular* if each vertex has degree $r-1$ or $r$.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be almost $r$-regular for $r\geq 2$, then $G$ contains an almost $(r-1)$-regular graph $H$ with $V(H)=V(G)$.

**Idea of proof.** Remove any edges that can be removed while keeping $G$ almost $r$-regular. Partition $V(G)$ in $A$ and $B$ s.t. vertices of degree $r$ are in $A$ while vertices of degree $r-1$ are in $B$. Note that no edge has both endpoints in $A$. If we find a matching from $A$ to $B$, we are done by removing all matching edges. So for each $S\subseteq A$ we want $|S|\leq|\Gamma(S)$| (Hall's condition).

**Problem.** By double-counting the edges between $S$ and $\Gamma(S)$ I only get $r\cdot|S|\leq(r-1)\cdot|\Gamma(S)|$. It seems reasonable that Hall is satisfied but I'm struggling to make it explicit.

Comment: What does it mean by "make it explicit" please?

Comment: Rather good question, see comment to answer below. I basically struggled to see $\frac{r-1}r\leq 1$. x_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really only missing a very small last insight.

Disregarding the edges "inside" $\Gamma(S)$, every vertex of $S$ has degree $r$, so $r|S|$ edges from $S$ arrive at $\Gamma(S)$. Since each vertex of $\Gamma(S)$ can only accommodate at most $r-1$ edges, $\Gamma(S)$ must have more than $|S|$ vertices.

So Hall is satisfied and you are done.

Comment: Weird. For some reason I didn't see that $r\cdot|S|\leq (r-1)\cdot|\Gamma(S)|$ already implies hall. I think I actually mixed up $r$ and $r-1$ in my head. Thanks for elucidating …