# $d$ Regular graph with edge induced $d-1$ regular subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n$ be even and $G=(V,E)$ be a $d$ regular graph on $n$ vertices. I am wondering whether I can find a subset $E'\subset E$ with $2|E'|=n(d-1)$ such that $G'=(V,E')$ is a $d-1$ regular graph. I found a more general question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1788391/614912) but I could not find a way to make it work for me.

I tried proofing it using an idea linked to urns. I put all edges in an urn and I draw an edge $e$ which I remove from $G$. Additionally, I remove $e$ as well as all edges incident to $e$ from said urn. In the next turn I again draw an edge from the now smaller pool of edges, remove it from $G$, remove it and all edges incident to it from the urn. And so on. Intuitively, this seems to work (using examples) but I just do not manage to obtain a rigorous proof, for example with a result that after $\frac{n}{2}-1$ draws there only remains one edge in the urn and so the degree of all vertices is exactly reduced by one.
Some help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just finding a perfect matching? There are well-studied algorithms that do this.

Comment: *A maximum-cardinality matching, to be more precise--if there is such a set $E'$ of vertices, then $E \setminus E'$ is a perfect matching and so any maximum-cardinality matching is perfect and will do. If there is not such a set $E'$ of vertices, then the maximum-cardinality matching is not perfect equivalently no perfect matching.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I am not experienced in graph theory so sometimes I am simply lacking the right terms.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that $G'$ is connected if $G$ is connected? I guess by removing a perfect matching (given its existence) one might run into disconnected $G'$ even though $G$ is connected?